# get_posts() loop returns the same the_title() for each post

Tags: query, get-posts, get-the-title

I'm using `get_posts()` to fetch posts from a particular category to display at the top of my homepage, separate from the main homepage Loop. Everything seems to work fine, but for the title (returned through `the_title()`) which is always the same; the title of the first post fetched by `get_posts()`. `the_permalink()` does the same as well, but `the_excerpt()` returns the correct result for each post.

Here's my code (I have removed only a few lines for fear I might inadvertently remove what is causing this problem):

```
$query = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'=>-1,
    'category'=>3
    ));
$events = array();

if ($query) {
    foreach ($query as $tpost) {
        $fields = get_post_custom($tpost->ID);
        if (isset($fields['event_start'])) {
            $usetime = $fields['event_start'][0];
            if (isset($fields['event_end'])) {
                $usetime = $fields['event_end'][0];
                }
            if ($usetime>time()) {
                $events[] = array("post"=>$tpost,"fields"=>$fields);
                }
            }
        }
    usort($events,function($a,$b){
        $a = $a['fields']['event_start'][0];
        $b = $b['fields']['event_start'][0];
        if ($a==$b) { return 0; }
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
        });
    }

if (count($events)>0) { ?>
    <div class="pad10 tac">
    <h2 class="mar10">Upcoming Events</h2>
    <div class="tiles">
    <?php foreach ($events as $event ) { ?>
        <?php setup_postdata( $event['post'] );?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class='noshow'>
        <div class="tile smalltile"><div id='post-<?php the_ID(); ?>'>
            <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
            <b><?php
            echo(date_i18n("D, F j @ g:ia",$event['fields']['event_start'][0]));
            ?></b>
            <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
        </div></div>
        </a>
    <?php }?>
    </div></div>
<?php }?>
```

I'm really scratching my head on this, especially as this code is, for the most part, based off of the `get_posts()` example from [this article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-queries-wordpress/), where it is reportedly working fine.

I'm thinking that this likely has something to do with my use of setup_postdata, but I suppose this is really just wild speculation.

Comment: The Codex page for [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) explains why this doesn't work and how to fix it.

Comment: @Milo Ah, of course, I should have realised. Thank you! Would you like to write this as an answer, so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 3):

Making Milos's comment into an answer....

The problem you are facing is the result of many wordpress template oriented functions expect some global variables. In `WP_Query` based loops setting those variable is done by calling the `the_post()` method of the `WP_Query` object, but with `get_posts` you need to call `setup_postdata()` for that.

My personal preference is to just try to avoid functions like `the_title` in favor of functions like `get_the_title`, that accept an explicit post id, whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setup_postdata()` for that.

**Important** `setup_postdata()` does not assign the global `$post` variable so it’s important that you do this yourself.

**Important** use `wp_reset_postdata()` after your foreach loop.

For more information visit:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/

```
<?php
    // Get posts
    global $post;
    $posts = get_posts([
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => 6
    ]);
?>

<?php foreach ($posts as $key => $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h3>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </h3>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```